# Using MyGeneration with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I found a fantastic template for NHibernate code generation using MyGeneration here,

http://vucetica.blogspot.com/2009/01/nhibernate-template-for-mygeneration.html

This creates XML mapping files with the extension hbm.xml.

I was wonder if anybody knows of templates which support fluent NHibernate which defines the mapping using C# files.

Thanks

Comment: I am not aware of any solution for this that exists and I've looked.

Comment: Maybe one day we will make our own template, I will publish it in that case. Too early to say which way we will go.

Comment: Any other NHibernate code generation tools that anybody would suggest? I have tried some of them, and most of them are not that great. We are using MSSQL 2008.

Comment: I'm also wondering if there is a fluent template... would be awesome if there was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using Fluent NHiberate you needn't hbm files, you can [generate](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping) them based on your domain model and [conventions](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions)

Comment: Aren't you assuming that the domain model / classes already exist?  What if the OP has a database but no classes defined and wants to auto-generate the classes?

Comment: Using auto mapping is an option, but it might not be flexible enough. Hard to say at this stage. I will keep it in mind though - it is good to know about. Thanks.